# How To Force Most Recent File Contents In Javascript Upload

Tags: jquery, file, input

I am uploading Excel files using an input with type='file'.  Works just fine.  I collect the file object from the input when the user does his browse/selection and then append that to a FormData object during an AJAX POST later on.

But I notice that if I update the Excel file externally without going through the file selection process again (e.g. $("#input").on("change", function(e)...) that the contents of the file haven't changed.

I would guess then that the file is actually loaded at the time of selection rather than at the point I append it to my form data.

It seems that if I want the latest version of the file, I have to make the user go through the selection process again on essentially the "same" file.

Is there a way to always get the latest version of a file without forcing the user to go through the selection process again?

Comment: what happen if you force the change $("#input").change()

Comment: Tried that.  Doesn't seem to do anything.  I'm thinking that it actually has to go through the selection process.

Answer (score 0):

When I fill an input type file and after modify the content when I check the size of the file it has been changed. An solution is to check on timeout the size of the file and trigger a .change on input before.
Edit: trigger change does not work on ie so instead I reappend the element at the same place and check the size after.

```
<div id="parentForm">
  <form><input type="file" /></form>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (function($){
        var inpt = $('input[type=file]')[0]
        var form = $('form')[0];
        var size = 0;
        var $parentForm = $('#parentForm');
        var checkSize = function(){
            var f = inpt.files[0];
            var newSize;
            if(f){
                newSize = inpt.files[0].size
                if(newSize != size){
                    $('form').trigger('sizeChanged')
                    size = newSize;
                }
            }
            setTimeout(function(){
                console.log('icheck')
                $parentForm.append(form);
                checkSize()
            },2000)
        }
        checkSize();

        //////////////////////

        $('form').on('sizeChanged',function(){
                console.log("the size has changed")
        })



    })(jQuery)    
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bormat/ufhhj4bd/11/

Comment: Waiting in my code a bit after changing the Excel file doesn't seem to make a difference in the size.  What does your HTML look like?

Comment: the minimum code without doctype <form><input type="file/></form> and in console when write checkSize() i see a difference

Comment: I guess I just don't understand here:  What actually triggers the file selection in this code?  I put this code into a page, but it just blows up when it hits the line "f = inpt.files[0]" and says that inpt is undefined.  Could you perhaps set up a fiddle for this?  Thanks!

Comment: in fact they are no event, the only solution I found is to check every 500 milisecond if size hasChanged and i add the trigger of change too https://jsfiddle.net/ufhhj4bd/2/

Comment: AHA!  Works in Chrome, not IE!  So, I need to ask for at least an IE solution here.

Comment: Basically, IE is caching the file at the time of selection and the other browsers don't.  So far I haven't been able to find any way in IE to force a reload of the file programmatically.  It does reload if the user manually reselects it.

Comment: I am not sure about this but maybe you can use activeX for IE .

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1995174.aspx?Get+file+size+before+upload+in+IE8

Comment: It appears that IE is not properly interfacing with the OS to understand that there have been changes made to the file.  It's not that IE is actually caching the file.

Comment: I solve the problem by reappend the element at the same place every 2seconds(or the time you want). I have edit my answer with new code seems that on IE .change() does not trigger the check of size but reappend the element yes. Strange fact .html() does not work but append yes. Test on ie11

Comment: I am fascinated that this actually works.  I need to run more tests to make sure there are no side-effects and such.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, almost!  Works fine with text files, but still doesn't see a change in an Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: I used all my imagination ^^, I tried with date instead of size tried to wrap unwrap with iframe, to set a value, to change the type, to click on browse, to put .text before .xlsx but it is IE and he has limit. So the only possibility is to upload the file by ajax with and send an FormData of the form and I don't know if you can just look on the server side the size of the file and after abort the upload.

Comment: ActiveX works for ie but the user has to reduce the security level of his browser and enable init activeX. the code for size is:  var objFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); 
   var filePath = $('input')[0].value;
   var objFile = objFSO.getFile(filePath);
   var newSize = objFile.size

Comment: work perfectly in local but on jsfiddle I got an error but it seems it is because I use jquery so translate the code without jQuery should work.